# Can't import .py from another directory

Tags: python, directory, path, python-import

I'm trying to make unit tests for my train.py file. But I can't import the train.py file. I've tried everything in comments on my screenshot.
the structure is as follow:

```
project/
   train.py
unit_tests/
   train_test.py
```

[image]

[1]:

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your actual project structure? It could be that you need to do a relative import.
As example:

```
from .project import train
from ..project import train
from . import train
```